# Algorithms for finding similar questions based on another question's title?

Tags: algorithm, search

For example, every time I post I question on stackoverflow.com, the UI suggest me plenty of
similar questions. How is it functionality implemented? Are there some well-written algorithms about this?

Comment: This belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: and it's asked multiple times - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282112/how-does-the-so-find-similar-questions-posted

Comment: @Nate: That question has been deleted.

Comment: This does *not* belong on meta. I understand it as "How would I implement such a feature" which is a valid SO question.

Comment: Removed the belongs-on-meta tag. Whether it actually belongs there or not, these tags are discouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/change-the-belongs-on-serverfault-tag-when-a-question-is-moved-to-serverfault/4211#4211

Comment: This is a legitimate programming question for an algorithm which also happen to be implemented on SO, and whose duplicate has been deleted. Please keep it open on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use the full text search feature in MSSQLServer

http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture

> SQL Server's full text search is used extensively for the site search and detecting if a question has already been asked. Lucene.net is considered an attractive alternative.

I think they talk about in it one of the podcasts too?

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the whole source  code for StackOverflow right here.  It's pretty easy to understand:

```
class StackOverflow
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JonSkeet();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need a Console.Read() after JonSkeet() so the application might stay alive if there is no question left ;)